# Reassign object with different constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, assignment-operator, assign, default-constructor

In class `MyClass`, I have a member `Dialog dialog_`.

After `MyClass`'s constructor is called, I want to call a different constructor for `dialog_` with parameters that are created in `MyClass`'s constructor (that's why I can't directly call the different constructor for `dialog_`, but just the default one).

So I tried

```
dialog_ = Dialog(/* different constr. w/ parameters passed from MyClass */);
```

But that doesn't work. The error is

```
Error: no operator "=" matches these operands
operand types are: Dialog = Dialog
```

So I Googled a bit and found in [this SO thread (3rd answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166099/calling-a-constructor-to-re-initialize-object) a code snippet which I tried:

```
dialog_.~Dialog();
new(&dialog_) Dialog(/* different constr. w/ parameters passed from MyClass */);
```

And it works. The answer in the thread though states "**The value of this does not go beyond purely theoretical though. Don't do it in practice. The whole thing is ugly beyond description.**"

So what can I do to solve my problem without using that obviously frowned upon piece of code?

I hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, the destructor-followed-by-constructor thing is evil. Don't do it. Ever.

Comment: Yes that snippet is horrible. I would suggest some form of "assign"/"reassign" method combination instead of relying on constructors.

Comment: @RichardHodges No, I'm not using C++11. And I know it's bad, that's why I'm asking here, but I lack the expertise to figure it out on my own ^^

Comment: in that case, either use option 1 from my answer, or see if you can refactor your class design so that it encapsulates smaller classes that you can construct in the initialiser list.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve what you want.

In c++98 you need to defer some of your initialisation to an init() function that you call from the constructor. This is a bit icky because it means a redundant construction and assignment for a number of your member variables.

In c++11 you can call 1 other constructor in the initialiser list, passing computed values (these values can be computed in static functions for cleanliness).

If you provide an example of your constructor code I can show you how to do it.

Comment: Sounds like he wants to delay initialization of a member.  I would suggest `boost::optional` for that

Comment: I don't know if we are talking about the same `init()` function, but I tried that earlier. That function had the same parameters as the second constructor but there was the same error as in my original post, except `Dialog` is replaced by another class that's a parameter... I'll explain it in another comment below:

Comment: `Dialog`'s two constructors are `Dialog()` and `Dialog(DialogType_ type, Resources &resources)`. `DialogType_` is just an enum in `Dialog`'s class. So the default constructor `Dialog()` is just empty, and the other constructor initialises `type_` to `type` and `resources_` to `resources` (both are member variables).

Comment: The error I am getting when I use the function `init(DialogType_ type, Resources &resources)` is about the `Resources`. It looks like this: `void Dialog::initialise(DialogType_ type, Resources &resources) {type_ = type; resources_ = resources;}`. The error is at the `resources_ = resources` line. I hope I could explain it :/

Answer (score 1):

You can put the Dialog member in a std::unique_ptr and then replace it when you need:

```
class MyClass {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Dialog> dialog_;

public:
    MyClass():
        dialog_( /* ... first constructor ... */ ) {}
    void setNewDialog(/* parameters */) {
        dialog_.reset(new Dialog(/* parameters */) );
    }
};
```

Comment: I have never worked with `std::unique_ptr`, but that sounds like a good and simple idea. If I use your example, do I need to take care of the `new` or will it automatically manage the memory?

Comment: std::unique_ptr owns the object and releases it in its destructor. But keep in mind that you have to write a copy-constructor if you want your class to be copyable.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing I've tried is working, so I'll just use

```
dialog_.~Dialog();
new(&dialog_) Dialog(/* ... */);
```

even though it's bad

Comment: What is wrong with the unique_ptr solution? The above code is on the level of really bad hacks and should only be used if you fully know what you are doing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187006/is-calling-destructor-manually-always-a-sign-of-a-bad-design: "Outside managing memory on a rather low level as above calling destructors explicitly, however, is a sign of bad design. Probably, it is actually not just bad design but outright wrong"

Comment: I tried to use std::unique_ptr but it introduced a lot of new errors in my existing code (because I'm drawing the dialog etc.). I'll try this approach again tomorrow when my frustration has watered down :P