# How to reuse object created in the stack

Tags: c++, object, constructor, stack

I'm not a C++ programmer, and I have great respect for its complexity, so I'd normally stay away from it. Despite this, I've found a certain library I'd like to tinker with.

The library includes a sample snippet where a single instance is allocated in local scope:

```
    Foo foo(arg1, arg2, ...);
```

I want to modify this example to re-initialize the object and do more things with it, but I can't do it via getters/setters or public variables. Is this possible without creating more instances?

In case there's no way of doing that without creating new instances, how could I release the memory of the objects I no longer need?

For instance, if it were a dynamic object, I guess it would be something like this:

```
    Foo* pfoo;

    pfoo = new Foo(arg1, arg2, ...);
    pfoo->doSomething();
    delete pfoo;

    pfoo = new Foo(arg3, arg4, ...);
    pfoo->doSomething();
    delete pfoo;
```

What would be the equivalent for the object allocated in the stack?

Comment: What do you mean by "re-initialize" the object? I would assume you mean call the constructor again, but then you mention something about getters/setters. Is this a possible duplicate of [Calling a constructor to re-initialize object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166099/calling-a-constructor-to-re-initialize-object)?

Comment: Your two choices are either setters/getters or making a brand new object. Since you said you are unable to use the former, then you must make a new object `Foo foo2(arg3, arg4, ..)`

Comment: The c++ way is that one object does one thing. Can't you just create two objects?

Comment: @MisterSmith: Your second example is usually bad style. You don't "reuse" pointers like this in C++. You just create a second pointer, unless you develop your software in an extremely special environment or with very unwieldy legacy code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way to release automatic variables is to let them fall out of scope:

```
void bar() {
  Foo f1(arg1, arg2);
  f1.doSomething();

  {
    Foo f2(arg3, arg4);
    f2.doSomething();
    // other stuff ...
    // f2 dies here.
  }

  {
    Foo f3(arg5, arg6); // allocated on stack, possibly overlapping f2's old spot
    f3.doSomething();
    // ...
    // f3 dies here.
  }

  // f1 dies here.
}
```

Comment: Not the _only_ way. You can use placement new - `Foo f(arg3, arg4); f.~Foo(); new(&f) Foo(arg5, arg6);`

Comment: OK, placement `new` works too, but that's more insane than goofy for vanilla automatic objects. :) And to be fair, I said *release*, which your example still requires of `f` eventually.

Answer (score 2):

If an object doesn't allow to reinitialize itself via public setters - you can not do it.

Actually, in your example you are not reinitializing *object*, you create another instance of `Foo` and reinitialize a *pointer variable* with address of this object.

Lifetime of local variable is limited to their scope. So you can split the scope of your function into smaller scopes:

```
void bar()
{
  {
    Foo foo(arg1, arg2, ...);
    foo.doSomething();
  }
  {
    Foo foo(arg3, arg4, ...);
    foo.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to post one more alternative for the OP, more along the lines of what he has suggested:

```
void somefunction()
{
    // create the first foo owned by a smart pointer
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> pFoo { new Foo { arg1, arg2, ... } };
    pFoo->doSomething();

    // now replace the old Foo with a new one
    pFoo.reset( new Foo { arg3, arg3, ... } );
    pFoo->doSomething();

    // no need to delete anything unless you specifically want the Foo to die now
    // in which case...
    // pFoo.reset();
} // implicit destruction of whatever pFoo owns happens here
```