# Is it legal to call a constructor twice for the same storage location?

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer

In C++, suppose I called a constructor two times for the same object. Then does the compiler allocate memory two times or simply once? Is it even legal?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of how you'd do this?

Comment: To do so, click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49392014/edit) link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a constructor to re-initialize object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166099/calling-a-constructor-to-re-initialize-object)

Comment: you cannot call the constructor more than once for a one object but you can call it recursively.

Comment: Calling the constructor each time will cause it to allocate memory each time. Although you can use 'placement new' to place the new memory allocation on top of where the previous one was for that object.

Comment: The answer depends entirely on how you managed to trick the compiler into generating code that you claim calls the constructor on the same object twice. Since you haven't shown that code, it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: @tadman I'm in a similar situation. My code (I'd like to know if it is allowed): `myClass * someFunction(int arg) { static myClass theObject(arg); return &theObject; }`

Comment: @MartinRosenau It's my understanding that `static` variables like this are constructed once, like a singleton. Depending on the implementation by the compiler, when the initialization actually occurs, this may or may not be thread safe.

Answer (score 3):

You can call a constructor multiple time on the same allocated storage, as long as you also call a destructor. But don't do it. I'll assume this is a purely theoretical question:

```
struct Object { virtual ~Object() {} };
{                                 // some scope
    Object obj;                   // constructed on automatic storage location
    obj.~Object();                // destructed
    new (&obj) Object;            // new object constructed on same storage
}                                 // destructor automatically called
```

Skipping the manual destruction might lead to undefined behaviour for objects with non trivial destructor<sup>1</sup>. Note **this is calling for troubles**; as an exercise: what happens if an exception is raised after `obj` has been manually destructed and `obj` has been manually reconstructed<sup>2</sup>?

---

<sup>1)</sup> [`[basic.life]/5`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#5.sentence-2)

> For an object of a class type with a non-trivial destructor, the program is not required to call the destructor explicitly before the storage which the object occupies is reused or released; however, if there is no explicit call to the destructor or if a delete-expression is not used to release the storage, the destructor shall not be implicitly called and any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined behavior.

<sup>2)</sup> Answer: [`[basic.life]/9`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#9.sentence-1).

Comment: But don't do it.

Comment: *"Skipping the manual destruction would lead to undefined behaviour."* -- Citation? Or at least an explanation of why you think that is the case?

Comment: 3.8/4 (C++14 numbering) is relevant guys. I don't think the destructor call is needed here (because `Object`'s destructor is trivial) although for style and maintenance reasons I would personally still use it.

Comment: And why not do it? This is how you make a pool allocator.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am so afraid of such constructs I tend to overestimate their consequences. I've edited my answer to be exact (I hope).