# Is a constructor, that is not a special member function, still a member function?

Tags: c++, function, constructor, language-lawyer, member-functions

From the C++ standard working draft:

> Default constructors ([class.default.ctor]), copy constructors, move constructors ([class.copy.ctor]), copy assignment operators, move assignment operators ([class.copy.assign]), and prospective destructors ([class.dtor]) are special member functions.

(https://eel.is/c++draft/special)

Given the following code:

```cpp
struct S {
    S(int, float, double);
};
```

In my understanding, the constructor of `S` is *not* a special member function, since it is neither a default constructor, copy constructor, nor move constructor.

I would like to know whether the standard still considers such as constructor a member function (or something "unique").

I read the parts of the C++ working draft about member functions, special member functions, and constructors, but didn't find anything reasonable answering this question. I also looked on StackOverflow, but most answers state that *all* constructors are considered special member functions, which seems to contradict the standard.

Comment: If you want to learn C++, please [read a good book or two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Don't read the specification.

Comment: I dont really understand what makes you doubt. *special* refers to those that can be compiler generated, and thats it. I mean eg `struct foo { void bar() {} };` is not special either, but that doesnt make it less member function

Comment: It is still a constructor, so you can still not call it as a function. But it is also not a special member function since the compiler cannot automatically create or delete them for you.

Comment: "...but most answers state that all constructors are considered special member functions, which seems to contradict the standard." can you refer to those answers? Either they are wrong or you misunderstood something, though we cannot tell unless you show us the answers

Comment: Perhaps those answers called the constructors "special" because they are not normal callable member functions?

Comment: Declarations inside **member specification** of the class are member declarations. If the declaration is of a variable it is called **member variable** and if the declaration is of a function, then it is called a **member function**. So yes, `S:: S(int, float, double)` is a member function. This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77968447/12002570).

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow are not normative for the C++ standard, and do not necessarily abide by the standard's terminology.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not trying to learn C++, I have multiple years of experience already. I just want to know the "formal definition" (in a "language lawyer" kind of sense). I'm not interested in the practical implications of it here.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai One example would be this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71680635/7540548 Another example is this question that states that (all) constructors are special member functions and nobody seems to disagree: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71724811/7540548 Another exampel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71830347/7540548 (quote: "A C++ constructor is a special member function") And there are more examples, but those were the ones I found.

Comment: @user12002570 Where does the standard define that a constructor is a function? I'd like to see a source for that.

Comment: @coder2k all constructors are special, but not all are special member functions ;). "special" can be used colloquially. The author of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71680635/4117728) explains what they mean with "special", eg you cannot get a pointer to a constructor, that is "special".

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I've added some more references that should make clear that all ctors are functions and hence member functions. Check out the updated answer.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai The answer in question starts with "Formally in the C++ Standard it is (along with several others) a **special member function** so yes it is a function, but it is a special function and not all of the normal rules apply." So the author doesn't use "special" in an everyday-fashion, but in the context of "special member function".

Comment: you are right. The answer is rather sloppy with regard to that.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai See [dcl.spec.auto.general](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto.general#3) that specifically says: *"the function declarator shall declare a function."* This definitely means/shows that ctor is a function. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tldr;**

A constructor is declared using a *function-declarator* and so it is a function and hence a member function.

---

##### Language-lawyered Explanation

[class.mem](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#general-1) states:

> **The member-specification in a class definition declares the full set of members of the class**; no member can be added elsewhere.
> A direct member of a class X is a member of X that was first declared within the member-specification of X, including anonymous union members ([class.union.anon]) and direct members thereof.
> **Members of a class are** data members, **member functions** ([class.mfct]), nested types, enumerators, and member templates ([temp.mem]) and specializations thereof.

Now we move onto [class.mem#general-3](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#general-3) to see what is a member function:

> A data member is a non-function member introduced by a member-declarator. **A member function is a member that is a function.**
> Nested types are classes ([class.name], [class.nest]) and enumerations ([dcl.enum]) declared in the class and arbitrary types declared as members by use of a typedef declaration ([dcl.typedef]) or alias-declaration. The enumerators of an unscoped enumeration defined in the class are members of the class.

Now we need to show that a ctor is a function so we move onto [class.ctor.general#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor.general#1.sentence-1):

> **A declarator declares a constructor if it is a function declarator** ([dcl.fct]) of the form
>
> ```
> ptr-declarator ( parameter-declaration-clause ) noexcept-specifieropt attribute-specifier-seqopt
> ```
>
> where the ptr-declarator consists solely of an id-expression, an optional attribute-specifier-seq, and optional surrounding parentheses, and the **id-expression has one of the following forms**:
>
> - in a friend declaration ([class.friend]), the id-expression is a qualified-id that names a constructor ([class.qual]);
> - **otherwise, in a member-declaration that belongs to the member-specification of a class or class template, the id-expression is the injected-class-name ([class.pre]) of the immediately-enclosing entity;**

The important thing to note is that a ctor is declared using a declarator which is a **function declarator**. Now to see that the *ctor's function declarator* declares a function we move onto [dcl.spec.auto.general](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto.general#3.sentence-3):

> A placeholder type can appear with a function declarator in the decl-specifier-seq, type-specifier-seq, conversion-function-id, or trailing-return-type, in any context where such a declarator is valid.
> **If the function declarator includes a trailing-return-type ([dcl.fct]), that trailing-return-type specifies the declared return type of the function.
> Otherwise, the function declarator shall declare a function.**
> If the declared return type of the function contains a placeholder type, the return type of the function is deduced from non-discarded return statements, if any, in the body of the function ([stmt.if]).

Now since the ctor's function declarator form doesn't include a trailing return type, the ctor's function declarator  declares a function as per the above [reference](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto.general#3.sentence-3).

Hence proved, the ctor `S::S(int, float, double`) is a function and so a member function.

##### Additional support

There is additional support for the statement that a constructor is a function in [dcl.constexpr](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#3.2):

> A function is constexpr-suitable if:
>
> - **if the function is a constructor** or destructor, its class does not have any virtual base classes.

This also indicates that a constructor is a function.

---

##### Layman Explanation

> Is a constructor, that is not a special member function, still a member function?

Yes, because the constructor `S::S(int, float, double)` is declared inside the **member-specification** of the class  `S` so the declaration is by definition a member function declaration.

Basically,  declarations inside the **member-specification** of the class are **member declarations**. If the declaration is of a

- variable, it is called **member variable** and
- if the declaration is of a function then it is called a **member function**.

---

So yes, `S::S(int, float, double)` is a member function.

Comment: I guess the spec is missing the term "constructor" in expansion of the "set of members". Everything about constructors points to the idea that they are not functions(their address cannot be taken). **Special member functions** is the only expression that referes to a few certain constructors as *member functions*. Thus IMHO the correct expression would be **special members**; and if specs state otherwise, then a revision of them is essential.

Comment: I'm still not 100 % convinved tbh. I didn't find a clear definition of what a constructor really *is* in the standard. The standard doesn't state that a constructor is a function. Clearly, a ctor is a "function-like thing", but I'm not trying to learn what a ctor does, but rather what its formal definition is. The part you quoted from the standard tells us the different kinds of members. But it doesn't say which kind of member a ctor (that's not a special member function) really is. I'd like to see a quote from the standard that says "constructors are member functions" or something alike.

Comment: @Red.Wave Yes, I think a clear definition is missing there in the standard.

Comment: @coder2k I guess you'll never find an explicit statement in std specs that defines a constructor to be a function. I think the spec can become more verbose about constructor not being a function. Long ago - when I was learning C++ through text books - the text used to stste that constructors are not functions. I guess nothing has changed in that regard; but the current spec wording is defected.

Comment: @Red.Wave I get the feeling that the standard has a defect here (which seems to be what you're saying). Constructors are not defined as functions, but constructors must be class (or struct) members but we don't know which kind of member they are. There's something missing.

Comment: @coder2k I've updated the answer with some more details/references to show that a ctor is a member function.

Comment: @Red.Wave *"Everything about constructors points to the idea that they are not functions..."* **No, this is wrong.** I've added some details that show that ctors are actually functions and hence member function as per the standard.

Comment: @user12002570 I'm afraid that seems to be just a missing representation. Constructors have properties that can not match those of a member function. They cannot be cv-ref qualified, they can be delegated, they have member inittializers, they cannot have a return type or value, they have no programmer accessible address. If a constructor contains a try-catch block, the catch block always rethrows. And at-least before C++11, text books used to make it clear that they were not functions. Constructors are toi different from functions, therefore they are never called functions.

Comment: @user12002570 the link you provided is just a totally new modification request. It doesn't reflect anything about standard committee's interpretation. But even if that change is accepted, it will be a new resolution. In the absence of a clear statement from standard spec, I still stick with the text book explanations which are more inline with the oddities of constructors. I don't mix destructors into this; they need a separate discussion.

Comment: @Red.Wave I know that it is a different modification request. My point was that the standard clearly mentions/states that a ctor is a function and also a member function. The textbooks are written based on the c++ standard not the other way round. You can't ignore the standard and say that because this textbook says this,  so the standard must be wrong.

Comment: @Red.Wave *"n the absence of a clear statement from standard spec..."* I already quoted the clar statement from the standard spec which is [A declarator declares a constructor if it is a function declarator...](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor.general#1.sentence-1)

Comment: @user12002570 Thanks for extending the answer. You added the parts of the standard that I also found before asking my question. If I interpret "A declarator declares a constructor if it is a function declarator of the form..." verbatim, it only tells me that the syntax for declaring a constructor is similar to the syntax for declaring a function. It just says "to declare a constructor, you have to write this", and the outcome of that action is, well, a constructor, but it does *not* state that a constructor indeed *is* a function. I'd agree to the rest of your line ot reasoning, though.

Comment: @coder2k You're missing the point that they have choosen to write the word "function" in the phrase "function declarator". Which is enough to mean/imply that anything that follows that form is a function. Essentially, a function declarator obviously has to be a function-declaration which in turn obviously declares a function. There is no need to write that separately as far as I understand it. If they were to omit the word "function" in "function declarator" then that would've been a problem.You're welcome.

Comment: @coder2k See [dcl.spec.auto.general](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto.general#3.sentence-3) that specifically says: *"the function declarator shall declare a function."* This definitely means/shows that ctor is a function. I think you missed this part. Updated the answer.

Comment: @user12002570 [dcl.spec.auto.general](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto.general#3.sentence-3) only speaks about function declarators that have a placeholder return type (i.e. `auto` or `decltype(auto)`).

Comment: @coder2k Yes I know, did you miss the word "otherwise" in [dcl.spec.auto.general](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto.general#3.sentence-3) which basically means that "when the placeholder is not used" which is true for ctors.

Comment: @user12002570 My problem with the sentence "A declarator declares a constructor if it is a function declarator ([dcl.fct]) of the form [...]" is that firstly the following grammar rule does not match any of the rules in [dcl.fct](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct). So I assume this is a totally new (and maybe unrelated?) grammar rule that defines how to declare a constructor. But it doesn't state that a ctor is a function. Secondly, a function declarator isn't said to declare a function (with the exception of those having placeholder return types, see above).

Comment: @user12002570 The "otherwise" in [dcl.spec.auto.general](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto.general#3.sentence-3) refers to the trailing return type. I think that paragraph is about return type deduction in case of a placeholder return type (e.g. `auto`) and no trailing return type (e.g. `-> int`) present.

Comment: @coder2k The "otherwise" there means that when the trailing return type is not used then the function declarator shall declare a function. And since this(that ctor don't/can't use trailing return type) is true for ctors, hence a ctor is a function.

Comment: @user12002570 I found [this interesting sentence](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#general-21.2). This would convince me of constructors being member functions. Do you agree? If you append this to your answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: @coder2k But ctors don't have names anyway. Also I don't think [that](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#general-21.2) proves/shows that a ctor is a member function.

Comment: @user12002570 Well, if that doesn't convince you, we won't find a clear answer here in my perspective :(

Comment: @coder2k I've already provided a clear/definitive answer which sums up to *"a function declarator shall declare a function"*. The above makes a ctor a function and hence a member function. If you think there is anything wrong with it or it doesn't apply that a ctor is a function, kindly state the reason.

Comment: @coder2k I've edited my answer to explain what the last quote means. See if it makes sense. In particular, I've added the statement *"
Now since the ctor's function declarator form doesn't includes a trailing return type, the ctor's function declarator  declares a function as per the above [reference](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto.general#3.sentence-3)."*

Comment: @user12002570 I understand that quote in the following way: If a function has a placeholder return type, but no trailing return type, then it declares a function and its return type is deduced by looking at the return statements in its body. I don't see why this should be applied to ctors since they don't have a placeholder return type.

Comment: @coder2k Ok let's go step by step.First, the quote says *"**If the function declarator** includes a trailing-return-type ([dcl.fct]), that trailing-return-type specifiesthedeclared return typeof the function.Otherwise, the function declarator shall declare a function."* Now askyourself does the ctor function declarator form `ptr-declarator ( parameter-declaration-clause ) noexcept-specifieropt attribute-specifier-seqopt` has any trailing return type?The answer is no it does not. This in turn implies that latter part(*"Otherwise, the function declarator shall declare a function."*) is applicble

Comment: @user12002570 I understand that logic, but I think the paragraph only applies to functions with a placeholder return type, so I don't think it applies to ctors. But I found another part that would also convince me, what do you think of [this](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#3.2)?

Comment: @coder2k *"but I think the paragraph only applies to functions with a placeholder return type..."* **Note that it is still under the section "Declarations"** Also it is quite clear that they are talking about function declarators(and hence functions) in addition to placeholder type in that clause.

Comment: @user12002570 Can't we just agree on that you add one of the two (or both) other parts of the standard that I mentioned to your answer to further support your point and then I can accept the answer? Even though I'm not totally convinced by your current answer, why not just add more arguments that support your conclusion? Wouldn't hurt, would it?

Comment: @coder2k Oh, actually I did not see [this link](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#3.2) that you provided. I only saw a [previous link](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#general-21.2). I am adding the former to my answer as an additional support.

Comment: @coder2k I've added [dcl.constexpr](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#3.2) into the answer.