# User-defined implicit conversion to bool not working for non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, initialization, metaprogramming

I was playing around with templates and I stumbled upon this setup:

```
template <typename T>
class is_callable {
    using Yes = char[1];
    using No = char[2];

    template <typename U> static Yes& filter(decltype(&U::operator()));
    template <typename U> static No& filter(...);

public:
    consteval operator bool() { return sizeof(filter<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(Yes); }
};


template <bool condition, typename T = bool>
struct enable_if { };

template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { using type = T; };

template <typename Lambda, enable_if<is_callable<Lambda>{}>::type = true>
void doSomethingWithLambda(Lambda func) {

}
```

This compiles just fine, but when I change `is_callable<Lambda>{}` to `is_callable<Lambda>()`, the compiler tells me that `is_callable<T> (void)` is not a valid type for the non-type template parameter `condition`. What's happening here? Could it be that the compiler is parsing it as a function call instead of an initialization? Why would it do that? I initialize all sorts of stuff with `()` and it never mistakes that for a function call, why is it doing that here?

Comment: Implicit conversions are not considered during template argument deduction

Comment: isn't it because it's considered as function type? https://godbolt.org/z/xhhY5E8Gv

Comment: @AnoopRana The implicit conversion seems to be considered when I use {} to instantiate the is_callable class. Why is that?

Comment: @NikTedig Check out [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)(if not already) and also [type conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)

Comment: @AnoopRana Thanks, it's starting to clear up for me.

Comment: @AnoopRana Nevermind, I have a question regarding the most vexing parse: If I declare a class and then instantiate it like so: Object instance = Object(); It compiles correctly and does what I want. But shouldn't it assume that Object() calls a function called Object, because of the most vexing parse rule? I would expect it to fail compilation since there is no function called Object.

Comment: @NikTedig No, note that when you write `Object instance = Object();` it is **copy initialization** so most vexing parse doesn't come into picture. On the other hand, if you were to write `Object instance();` then there can be vexing. Moreover, note [constructor do not have names in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71680595/is-a-constructor-a-function-and-is-it-possible-to-call-a-constructor). Also, for more reading into this refer to [Is most vexing parse a formally defined concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71937565/is-most-vexing-parse-a-formally-defined-concept).

Comment: @NikTedig for a common example, when you declare a `std::function<int()>` it's not parsed as `std::function<0>`.