# How to call struct constructor in friend class function( C++)

Tags: c++, struct

I need some help

I have struct in class and I have struct construstor

```
class Book{

struct Page {

 char* line;

Page next=nullptr;

 Page(char *new_line):line(new_line){};  //struct constructor
};

Page* first = nullptr,*last=nullptr;

friend Book& operator+=(Book &k, const char* new_line);

};
```

How to call struct constructor `Page(char new_line){line=new_xline}` in function `friend Book& operator+=(Book &k, const char* new_line)`?

When I try:

```
Book& operator+=(Book &k, const char* new_line){

...

k.last->next = new Book::ListaBrojeva(new_line)
```

there is  error because I did not mention instance but I do not know how to do that `(new k.ListaBrojeva(new_line)` is also error but for itself **why** I can not do that )

```
k.last = k.last->next;
...

}
```

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: Constructors are not "called" directly in C++, in any sense of that term as it is commonly used in C++. C++ simply does not work this way. A constructor is "called" indirectly by constructing and instance of the class. That's why its name is "constructor". So, to do that, you need to construct an instance of the class and specify the correct parameters.

Comment: [You can't call a constructor directly in C++.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71680595/is-a-constructor-a-function-and-is-it-possible-to-call-a-constructor)

Comment: `char* line;`  Are you sure? Don't you mean `std::string` this is C++ after all

Comment: `Page next=nullptr;` should be `Page *next=nullptr;`

Comment: I *guess* that you get an error trying to convert `const char*` to `char*` in `operator+=`, but we can't tell without [mcve].

Comment: I disagree that "can you call constructor" is an answer to this question. OP simply misused word "call" when they meant "create an object". Quite a common mistake for beginners, since creating an object is hardly distinguishable from "calling" constructor.

Comment: @user12002570 that would still be a very "C" like way of doing things. In current C++ it should not be needed to use pointers for this. (there is no dynamic polymorphism involved)

Comment: Why do you want `operator+=` to be a non-member? It's a pretty odd choice.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I was pointing out the typo when I said `Page next=nullptr;` should be `Page *next=nullptr;`. Or were you referring to the previous comment the one with "you can't call a ctor"?

Comment: Side note: if this is homework/educational purposes and you have to use clunky stuff like `char` arrays for strings and roll-your-own linked lists you need to call that out in the question. Otherwise folks will, and have, answer the question the idiomatic (and more effective) way.

Comment: @user12002570  I was trying to say your correction is ok, but that the final corrected code would still be "C" like. But I should have said "it would still be a useless use of a pointer" ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yeah, saw some mistakes for last few days(yesterday).

Comment: ```Page next=nullptr``` will likely cause some "incomplete type" compilation issue. You should probably use ```Page *next=nullptr```. 

Also do you mean: ```friend Book &operator+=(Book &k2, const Book &k2);``` ?

Answer (score 1):

In C++ I would expect something a bit more like this :

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Line
{
public:

    std::string content;
};

class Page
{
    void AddLine(const std::string& text) 
    {
        m_lines.push_back(Line{text});
    }

    Page& operator+=(const std::string& text)
    {
        AddLine(text);
        return *this;
    }
  
private:
    // or maybe std::list<Line> if you want insertion to be faster
    std::vector<Line> m_lines;
};
```