# What are the different between calling constructor and calling function pointer of constructor in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, constructor, function-pointers

This question is asked with purpose to enhance my understanding.

I was trying to dynamically load a native DLL, and notice a phenomenon that I can't get over my head.

So given my DLL has the following oversimplified exported class.

```
ClassA {

    SubClassA subClass;

    ClassA() {
        subClass = new SubClassA;
    }

    ~ClassA() {
        delete subClass;
    }
}
```

I tried two approach to link to the DLL and call the constructor in a separate C++ console project:

Approach 1: Static Link (success)

```
#include <ClassA.h>


void main() {

    ClassA* myClass;
    myClass = new ClassA();

}
```

Approach 2: Dynamically Link (failed with Memory Access Violation)

```
#include <ClassA.h>
#include <windows.h> 

void main() {

    HMODULE m_NativeLibraryHandle;
    
    ClassA* myClass;
    typedef ClassA* (__stdcall* ClassAConstructor)();
    ClassAConstructor p_Constructor;

    m_NativeLibraryHandle = ::LoadLibrary(L"ClassA.dll");
    p_Constructor = (ClassAConstructor)GetProcAddress(m_NativeLibraryHandle, "decoratedNameofConstructor");

    myClass = p_Constructor();
}
```

Debugging in the DLL project shows that the violation is thrown at `subClass = new SubClassA;`, where the `this` pointer shows "unable to read". (My guess is the `new SubClassA` is failed to be assigned to the `subClass`.)

What is the actual different that is between the above two method to caused the different in behavior? My understanding is that, `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` is basically doing what Linker is doing, so theoretically they should behave similar.

Comment: There can be no function pointer to constructor in c++. Because [constructors don't have names and cannot be directly called by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71680595/is-a-constructor-a-function-and-is-it-possible-to-call-a-constructor). That is, you cannot form a pointer to a constructor.

Comment: *"A in depth lecture is much welcomed...."* I don't think SO is for this. Take a [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: `ClassA {` this isnt C++, is it?

Comment: "oversimplified" -- sorry, that was really too much. Please provide a [mcve]!

Comment: `subClass = new SubClassA;` is not correct c++ either when `subclass` is of type `SubClassA`

Comment: please read about [mcve]. Removing unrelated stuff and posting a simplified example is what you should do, but you shouldnt post fantasy code

Comment: I did came across the say of "no function pointer to constructor". For now I cannot adapt to it yet without understanding it.

Comment: `typedef ClassA* (__stdcall* ClassAConstructor)();` this simply isnt the type of the constructor. When you do the c style cast you force the cast no matter if the cast makes any sense or not, but it doesnt make sense and you get UB when trying to call the function. I don't think there is much more to learn here

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Sorry, but I really did my best to provide a simplified example.

Comment: @user12002570 Hi, I will look further on that post. I am terribly sorry about the constructor part.

Comment: I am terribly sorry about unprofessional question. I do have question related to the direct call and function pointer, and this question is definitely misleading. Sorry about this.

Comment: @CharonEXE Don't worry about it. We all made mistakes when we were new to the site. Happens to all. In the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71680595/is-a-constructor-a-function-and-is-it-possible-to-call-a-constructor) I linked, you'll find the explanation that we can't form a pointer to a constructor. So the code isn't valid.

Comment: A constructor does not return an object but takes a pointer to the object to be created (it is called on your behalf "behind the scenes" during object construction). You can't create a valid object by calling it manually.

Comment: The basic thing is constructors are not functions (and thus you cannot construct function pointers to them). Before you even continue. Exporting C++ (classes/types) from dll's has its own set of issues. The host executable and the dll's it load must be from the same compiler and must be ABI compatible. So I recommend either static linking or adding an extern "C" interface to your dll

Comment: here the issue is more clear https://godbolt.org/z/7YKoPcKs7

Comment: your signature of `p_Constructor` is wrong. must be `ClassA* (* p_Constructor)(ClassA* )` - you must pass pointer to `this` to constructor as 1 parameter

Comment: @user12002570 - constructor have name and can be direct called, probably not form c/c++ but from asm possible. or if it exported, as in this case

Comment: @RbMm No, as per the c++ standard [constructors do not have names](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class#ctor-1.sentence-2). Refer to [this link](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class#ctor-1.sentence-2). There are also many many related SO posts for this.

Comment: @user12002570 it have name. use `__pragma(message(__FUNCDNAME__))` for view it. if you can not access constructor by name, this not mean that nobody can not.

Comment: @RbMm I think you misunderstood what I'm saying which is that as far as the c++ standard is concerned(i.e., from the viewpoint of c++ standard), *constructors do not have names*. That does not mean that implementation cannot provide some way to find their name. That is, what you provided in your last comment using `__pragma` is non-standard. There is also the [as-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule) rule in c++.

Comment: @user12002570 i understand that you mean c++ standards, but by fact any function have internal name. in any implementation. for concrete question - if we **export** function - it will be have name and will be separate function (without export compiler can at all inline constructor code and no function at all). also we can call function (if it not inlined) by name from asm. this of course out of bounds of c++ standards

Comment: @RbMm The reason I am mentioning this is because OP seems to be not aware of this(that ctor do not have names in C++) and can therefore unknowingly invoke undefined behavior in their program due to this. Whether the program works for a given compiler is up to the implementation ofcourse. So they(OP) should be aware of portability issues(or that might invoke UB) about their programs.

Comment: @user12002570 error of OP in wrong signature of constructor - he not pass **this** pointer to it. constructor is member function always. also can be problem with new/delete different implementations (at destructor time) between exe and dll

Comment: @RbMm That is the thing, c++ also doesn't guarantee that there is anything called *implicit this parameter*. It's just that compiler usually implement a member function as if they have a first parameter of a pointer type to class called `this`. But the C++ standard itself doesn't have any concept of *implicit this parameter*. Instead what the standard has is something called *"implicit object parameter"* which is **only used** during overload resolution and is actually a reference type. I submitted a [CWG 2660](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2660.html) regarding this(pun intended).

Comment: @user12002570 here tag *winapi* and all windows implementations assume that *this* exist, all *COM* based on this for example

Comment: @RbMm Yup, the tag: `windapi` does imply this.

Comment: @RbMm COM makes absolutely zero assumptions about (implicit) `this` pointers. It doesn't require C++, so I wonder where you got this wild idea from. Windows' ABI is strictly based on C, and that's the contract Windows compilers have to agree on.

Comment: @IInspectable - this is false. *COM* based on assumption that every interface take pointer to self (*this*) as first parameter. in *C* this pointer explicity declared in headers and of course not declared in *C++*, but for be equal for *C* implementation need assume that member functions (despite and not constructr and only virtual) take *this* pointer. in any case this is fact, that constructor take *this* pointer, of try show/build example when this not true

Comment: @RbMm Maybe you can add some reference to a some official source which supports your claim that *"COM is based on assumption that `this` is used as member function parameter"*. Btw not my downvote to your answer.

Comment: @user12002570 look at any windows header file, which use com interfaces. for example *objidl.h* and compare *C* and *C++* definitions of any iterface. you can view that in *C* any method take `I... * This,` as first parameter, in *C++* this is implicit. however dispute was about my use of union. i use fact that [*non-static data members of a union object have the same address*](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#general-note-2). so `p_Constructor` and `pv` share exactly the **same** memory. and have the same representation. if this is wrong - the `reinterpret_cast<*>(pv)` will be also wrong

Comment: @user12002570 simply usually used `reinterpret_cast<*>(pv)` form.but if very want - try prove that this is correct from pure *c++* view and not UB. that this `reinterpret_cast` is legal. if it legal the `p_Constructor` and `pv` must have the same binary representation. and in this case code with union also legal. really all dispute based on personal deep hostility and not on technical issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling a constructor and calling a function pointer of a constructor in C++ are very similar in the sense that they are both ***quite impossible***:

- You cannot call a constructor in C++.
- You cannot obtain a pointer to a constructor in C++.

According to [the C++ spec](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) about constructors:

> Constructors have no names and cannot be called directly.

So, in C++, you do not call constructors. The language does that for you when you use the `new` keyword, when you declare an object on the stack, etc. The expression `new MyClass()` might look like a constructor invocation, and it does in fact ***contain*** a constructor invocation, and so it might be mistaken for a constructor invocation, but that's not what it is; it is a "new expression", which includes, among other things, an invocation of a constructor. But the other things are crucial: you cannot just skip them and directly invoke the constructor.

Function pointers of constructors do not exist because normally you cannot take the address of a constructor. If you examine the names exported by the DLL, and somehow figure out which name corresponds to the constructor, and use that name to obtain the entry point of that constructor from the DLL, you are cheating: you are doing something which is not normally supported by the language. As a result, you should not attempt to invoke that entry point. A constructor is only supposed to be invoked by the language.

Also according to the C++ spec:

> A constructor is a special ***non-static*** member function of a class.

(Emphasis mine.)

A constructor assumes that memory has been allocated, and proceeds to initialize that memory. The language takes care of the memory allocation, but invoking the constructor directly does not. Since a constructor is non-static, it expects an uninitialized `this` to be passed to it, but you are not allocating any memory and you are not passing anything to the constructor. The result is exactly as expected: a crash.

And besides, think about it: the constructor could not be internally allocating the memory, because how would it work then if the object was allocated on the stack? And how would it work if the constructor was being invoked by the constructor of a derived class which presumably occupies more memory?

You can get your DLL to work by using a ***factory method***.  A factory method is a public static method which executes `new ClassA()` and returns the result, or declares `ClassA()` and returns it by value.  Then, obtain the address of the factory method from the DLL, and invoke it.

Comment: *"A constructor is only supposed to be invoked by the `new` keyword."* No, what about constructing on the stack? And manually calling `new` is usually a bad practice, the factory method can return by value or `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ok I will reword it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat there, I think I fixed it, please let me know if there is anything else.

Comment: I'd still recommend to return by value from factory methods, looks good otherwise.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ok, I made one more edit.

Comment: Ok, thanks. (The downvote isn't mine.)

Answer (score -1):

Constructor is a member function, and it takes pointer to `this` as its first argument. So your signature is wrong. Instead it must be

```
ClassA* (* p_Constructor)(ClassA* )
```

and in case you want to call constructor directly - you first need allocate memory for struct/class (and know it exact size) and pass pointer to this memory to constructor. formal code can be next (I'm not using dll to avoid extra code)

```
struct __declspec(dllexport) ClassA {

    int* subClass;

    ClassA() {
        __pragma(message(__FUNCDNAME__))
        subClass = new int;
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>(%p)\n", __FUNCTION__, this, subClass);
    }

    ~ClassA() {
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>(%p)\n", __FUNCTION__, this, subClass);
        delete subClass;
    }
};

    if (ClassA* p = (ClassA*)LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, sizeof(ClassA)))
    {
        union {
            PVOID pv;
            ClassA* (* p_Constructor)(ClassA* );
        };

        if (pv = GetProcAddress((HMODULE)&__ImageBase, "??0ClassA@@QEAA@XZ"))
        {
            p_Constructor(p);
            p->~ClassA();
        }

        LocalFree(p);
    }
```

However using such code is bad idea anyway. Correct solution - export static fuction, which create class object and call it. all used class functions - make virtual, instead direct export. use AddRef/Release instead export and directly call *ClassA::`scalar deleting destructor'*

```
class ClassA {

    int* subClass;
    LONG _M_dwRefCount = 1;

    ClassA() {
        subClass = new int;
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>(%p)\n", __FUNCTION__, this, subClass);
    }

    virtual ~ClassA() {
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>(%p)\n", __FUNCTION__, this, subClass);
        delete subClass;
    }
public:
    virtual void WINAPI Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_M_dwRefCount))
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    virtual void WINAPI AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&_M_dwRefCount);
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) static ClassA* WINAPI createObj()
    {
        __pragma(message(__FUNCDNAME__));
        return new ClassA;
    }
};


union {
    PVOID pv;
    ClassA* (WINAPI * createObj)();
};
if (pv = GetProcAddress((HMODULE)&__ImageBase, "?createObj@ClassA@@SAPEAV1@XZ"))
{
    if (ClassA* p = createObj())
    {
        p->Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Accessing a union member that's not the active union member is UB in C++.

Comment: @IInspectable we already not once speak about this. Even your formal rule have documented exception. In current case we have 2 pointers with the same address, which is exactly guaranteed

Comment: Which specific language rule allows this?

Comment: @IInspectable 2 pointers share the same memory address ( or register) and have the same representation. As result binary value will be the same. This code will be work correct in any compiler. If you not agree, try create example, when this code can "fail" . Use any level of optimization, etc. try . But with exactly my code. Will be very interesting look for your UB Poc

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#general-note-1 and are this is one only ? Why here access "not active" not UB. This is only bad draft

Comment: There is no common initial sequence here. The rule doesn't apply. And function pointers do not need to have the same properties as regular pointers. As far as the proof goes, you've got things backward: **You** have to prove the absence of UB. And you're not doing a good job with that. Oh well, maybe, some day, you'll eventually get it.

Comment: @IInspectable simply draft use bad language. Why in this narrow case is possible access "not active" . Are this is single exception? If 2 structs begin with some fundamental type is ok. But if we have struct and standalone fundamental type - not ok already? Really? And here no "function" pointer. GetProcAddress return pointer. You can not create POC, how, why, this code can be wrong. Really it always will be correct

Comment: The code is **always** wrong. It's just a peculiar property of UB that it is difficult to demonstrate. The idea that UB must always manifest itself in some particular way for it to be legit UB is just testament to the fact that you're still struggling to grasp how programming languages work.

Comment: @IInspectable the code is always correct and will be work as excepted. you can not build example, with with every imaginable level of optimization that would cause this code to not work correctly.

Comment: Let's postpone this argument until after you've understood how programming languages work,

Comment: @IInspectable It’s not for you to judge who understands what. the draft is poorly worded in this area. if we use `union { STARTUPINFOEXW six;  STARTUPINFOW si; DWORD  cb; }` the `six` and `si` have *common initial sequense* and can not query standalone `cb` ?! this is funny. why at all we can query "not active" member at all ? if all member have the **same** start address ( register is also address) which is documented, question only in internal representation of 2 members. and in case 2 pointers it equal. and `GetProcAddress` not return *function* pointer. it return general pointer

Comment: @IInspectable the code will be work correct and you know this. and this will be in ay compiler with any optimization and assumptions. because 2 pointers share the same memory (exactly and this documented) and have the same internal representation. this is draft problem if it can not good formulate this point