# Can I call a constructor of an object in a method of another object?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, inner-classes

I am an amateur in C++. I have a question about the data constructor. Can I initialize the parent class first and then call the constructor of the member class within a member method?

```
class Data{
    public: 
    Data(datalist);
    setPar();
    getPar();

private:
    //other variables
};

class MainProg{
public:
    MainProg();
    dataInput();
    dataProcess();
    dataOutput:
private:
    Data dataobj;
};

MainProg::dataInput(parlist){
    ..... //read data here
    dataobj(datalist);
}
```

Comment: [Calling a constructor to re-initialize object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2166099)

Comment: please don't show us pseudocode that looks like C++. Creat a [mre] of what you want.

Comment: Note: all class members are initialized before the program enters the body of the constructor, so `MainProg`'s constructor must initialize `dataobj` and must supply a valid `datalist` in order to initialize `dataobj`. You'll have to rethink how you intend to approach this problem.

Comment: Note: C++ doesn't reward guesswork very often and is too complicated to be learned via Stack Overflow questions. If you have not already, I strongly recommend getting and reading [a good introductory book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

You can call the destructor and then the constructor

```
dataobject.~Data();
dataobject(datalist);
```

but you really really shouldn't.

Why can't you assign to `dataobject`?

```
dataobject = Data(datalist);
```

Or initialize in the constructor directly:

```
MainProg::MainProg(something parlist) : dataobject(read_data(parlist)) { }
static Data read_data(something parlist) { ... }
```

Or write a factory:

```
MainProg from_parlist(something parlist) {
    // read data here
    return MainProg(datalist);
}
```

or simply read the data in main before you create MainProg.

Comment: Thank you Goswin! Your answer really helped me on my current project. Thank you again!